# Сайт открывается только если явно указать порт после домена (nginx)

Tags: nginx

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему мой сайт открывается только если я буду переходить по адресу `boards.domain.ru:8000` либо `100.100.100.100:8000` (IP-адрес сервера). Любые другие комбинации (`boards.domain.ru`, `https://boards.domain.ru`, `https://boards.domain.ru:8000`) приводят к отображению страницы ошибки Nginx (502 - Default Gateway). В логах (лежащих по пути `/var/log/nginx/error.log`) есть следующая запись:

```
2023/01/27 13:51:11 [error] 2920#2920: *90 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 213.208.174.35, server: boards.domain.ru, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://focalboard/favicon.ico", host: "boards.domain.ru", referrer: "https://boards.domain.ru/"
```

Конфигурация виртуального хоста следующая:

```
upstream focalboard {
    least_conn;
    server localhost:8000;
    keepalive 32;
}

server {

    server_name boards.domain.ru;

    location ~ /ws/* {
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        client_max_body_size 50M;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
        proxy_buffers 256 16k;
        proxy_buffer_size 16k;
        client_body_timeout 60;
        send_timeout 300;
        lingering_timeout 5;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1d;
        proxy_send_timeout 1d;
        proxy_read_timeout 1d;
        proxy_pass https://focalboard;
    }

    location / {
        client_max_body_size 50M;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
        proxy_buffers 256 16k;
        proxy_buffer_size 16k;
        proxy_read_timeout 600s;
        proxy_cache_revalidate on;
        proxy_cache_min_uses 2;
        proxy_cache_use_stale timeout;
        proxy_cache_lock on;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass https://focalboard;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/boards.domain.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/boards.domain.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = boards.domain.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;

    server_name boards.domain.ru;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Спасибо большое за любую помощь!

Comment: Потому что в протоколе TCP за https закреплён порт 443 (за http — 80), и именно на него идёт обращение, если не указано иное.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов здесь написано `listen 443 ssl;`

Comment: `proxy_pass https://focalboard;` — вот здесь исправьте https на http

Comment: @andreymal, ой, спаси вас и сохрани :) Вы – чудо. Спасибо большое! Правда, если честно, не соображаю, почему: как-то с веб почти не работал.